# jQuery UI tooltip above a hoverable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I want a tooltip for an element (#hastitle) inside another element (#hover).
The latter stops event propagation and does something on mouseover/mouseout.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/IARI/d69j99jy/2/)

html:

```
<div id="hover">
    <div id="hastitle" title="bar">fu</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#hover').on('mouseover mouseout', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this)[e.type == 'mouseover' ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('hover');
});
$(document).tooltip({
    tooltipClass: 'tip'
});
```

Why does the tooltip not work?

Also for a solution: I'm not sure whether I want to call `e.stopPropagation()` on mouseover/mouseout for the element with the tooltip (#hover) yet.
So a solution that works for both cases would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the widget is initialized on `document`, the widget's event listeners will be attached to it. If we prevent event propagation it won't reach the handlers attached with `document`.

Simply allowing the event propagation seems to fix the issue for me.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/d69j99jy/3/)

---

If you must prevent event from propagating further `#hover`, You can initialize the widget on it rather than `document`:

```js
$('#hover').on('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).toggleClass('hover', e.type == 'mouseover');
});

$("#hover").tooltip({
  tooltipClass: 'tip'
});
```

```css
#hover,
#hastitle {
  padding: 25px;
}
#hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
#hover.hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
#hastitle {
  background-color: green;
}
.tip {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="hover">
  <div id="hastitle" title="bar">fu</div>
</div>
```